# How much radioactive decay in thoriated TIG rod (and total for decay chain)?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity

Among the stocked items in the maintenance supply shop I work are thoriated [tungsten inert gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_tungsten_arc_welding) (TIG) welding rods.  Remembering what I read several decades ago, [thorium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorium) is radioactive.  So, I was curious, just how much radioactivity is each of these TIG rods producing?

Below is my own personal research transcribed from a LaTeX document I created.  (I was practicing math, physics, and [TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) all at the same time.) :-)

My questions are:

1. Does the value I calculated (564.5 [Bq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Becquerel)) appear accurate? (i.e. correct math and physics calculations)
2. Since this only shows the radioactivity of the thorium, and [its decay chain has ten decay products](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Decay_Chain_Thorium.svg/498px-Decay_Chain_Thorium.svg.png), then is the total radioactivity ten times as much?
3. Six of the ten decays create an alpha particle.  Does this mean that the TIG rod is "producing" six $^{4}$He nuclei per decay event? (Imagining rod being "filled" with helium...)

### From my LaTeX document:

The TIG rod is a cylinder 2.4 mm in diameter and 175 mm long.  It is made of [2% thorium dioxide](https://www.orau.org/ptp/collection/consumer%20products/weldingrod.htm) (ThO$_{2}$) and the rest is tungsten.

Assumptions made:

- The proportions of tungsten and thorium dioxide are by volume, not mass.
- Thorium is comprised of a single isotope, $^{232}$Th, with a standard atomic weight of 232.0377 u.
- Oxygen has a standard atomic weight of 15.9995 u.  This is based on the natural terrestrial occurrence of the three stable isotopes of oxygen.
- Thorium's radioactive half-life ($t_{1/2}$) is [1.405 $\times$ 10$^{10}$ years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorium).
- Tungsten and oxygen are stable--all radioactivity is from the thorium.

> **NOTE**:  Modern accurate measurements indicate that all five naturally-occurring isotopes of tungsten are [*very mildly* radioactive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_tungsten), with each having a $t_{1/2}$ > 10$^{18}$ years.  This can be ignored for the purposes of this discussion.

- Thorium dioxide's density ($\rho$) is [10.00 g/cm$^{3}$](http://web.ornl.gov/info/reports/1962/3445603644849.pdf).
- Avogadro's constant ($N_{A}$) is 6.02214 $\times$ 10$^{23}$ mol$^{-1}$
- There are 3.15576 $\times$ 10$^{7}$ seconds in a year.

First, calculate the volume of the rod.  $V_{cylinder} = \pi r^{2}h$.

$$ V_{rod} = \pi \times (1.2 \text{ mm})^{2} \times 175 \text{ mm}
 = 791.6835 \text{ mm}^{3} = 0.7916835 \text{ cm}^{3}$$
Next, find the fractional volume of the ThO$_{2}$.

$$ V_{ThO_{2}} = 2\% \text{ of } V_{rod} = 0.02 \times 0.7916835 \text{ cm}^{3} 
= 1.583367 \times 10^{-2} \text{ cm}^{3} $$
Find the mass of the ThO$_{2}$.

$$ m_{ThO_{2}} = \rho_{ThO_{2}} \times V_{ThO_{2}} = 10.00 \dfrac{\text{g}}{\text{cm}^{3}} \times 1.583367 \times 10^{-2} \text{ cm}^{3} 
= 0.1583367\text{ g} $$
Calculate the mass fraction of thorium in ThO$_{2}$.
$$ M_{Th} = \dfrac{u_{Th}}{u_{Th} + 2 u_{O}} = \dfrac{232.0377\text{ u}}
{232.0377\text{ u} + 2 \times 15.9995\text{ u}} = 0.8788 ~M_{ThO_{2}} $$

Find the mass of the thorium given its fraction of the mass of ThO$_{2}$.
$$ m_{Th} = 0.8788 \times 0.1583367\text{ g} = 0.1391463\text{ g} $$
Calculate the number of moles of Th.  This is calculated by dividing the mass by its standard atomic weight.
$$ n_{Th} = \dfrac{m_{Th}}{u_{Th}} = \dfrac{0.1391463\text{ g}}{232.0377\text{ u}} 
= 5.99671 \times 10^{-4}\text{ mol}  $$
Multiply moles by Avogadro's Constant to find the number of thorium atoms in the rod.
$$ N_{Th} = (5.99671 \times 10^{-4}\text{ mol}) \times  
(6.02214 \times 10^{23}\text{ mol}^{-1}) = 3.6113035 \times 10^{20} $$
Convert thorium's half life from years to seconds.
$$ t_{1/2} = (1.405 \times 10^{10} \text{ yr}) \times \left(3.15576 \times 10^{7}
\dfrac{\text{s}}{\text{yr}}\right) = 4.43395977 \times 10^{17}\text{ s} $$
The activity (in Bequerels) is calculated by multiplying the number of thorium atoms by the natural logarithm of 2 divided by its half-life.
$$ A_{Th} = 3.6113035 \times 10^{20} \times \dfrac{0.69314718}{4.43395977 \times 10^{17}\text{ s}} = 564.544 \text{ Bq} $$
Thus, there are about 565 radioactive decays of $^{232}$Th each second in the thoriated TIG rod.
For reference, the [specific activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_activity) of pure thorium is 4075 $\dfrac{\text{Bq}}{\text{g}}$.

Comment: it's probably 2% by weight, not volume

Comment: what happens if you just put it on a geiger counter?

Comment: @wlexxx: I put the whole package (ten rods) on a geiger counter once (courtesy of the safety manager at my job).  Got a few steady clicks higher than ambient...

Answer (score 1):

Answer to #1:

Assuming the rod has 0.1391463 g of Th, and the specific activity of Th is 4075 $\dfrac{\text{Bq}}{\text{g}}$, then

$$ 0.1391463 \text{ g} \times 4075 ~\dfrac{\text{Bq}}{\text{g}} = 567 \text{ Bq} $$

Pretty close to my calculated value.

Comment: P.S. I added the specific activity to the question part just today (not in my original research paper).  [Link1](http://www.webmineral.com/help/Radioactivity.shtml#Table%202) [Link2](http://daun01.blogspot.com/2012/06/which-is-more-radioactive-potassium-40.html)